# Where can I find the Proof of Stake code that ethereum uses for consensus?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

I was exploring the go-ethereum implementation for college project and wanted to see and understand (try to) the code for Proof of Stake that ethereum uses. [Github](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum).

I am curious to know and also if there is any generalisation that it is always present under xyz directory or by abc name, for all open source blockchains, it will be really helpful.

Comment: There is no generalizations. It depends on blockchain developers. Check consensus directory. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/beacon/consensus.go

Answer (score 0):

The go-ethereum implementation "geth" is an execution client. Execution clients are no longer used for consensus, but only for managing transactions and Ethereum's state.

If you want to read the current proof of stake code, then you need to take a look at one of the consensus client implementations listed [here](https://clientdiversity.org/) (e.g. the [prysm client](https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm)).